# Bootstrap modal not working when placed in container-fluid

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display modal when clicking on a button which is added dinamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rent-php').on('click', '.bike-rent-btn', function(){
        $('#confirm-rent-modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

The button which is added dinamically via php looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md bike-rent-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-rent-modal">Rent</button>
```

This is the html code, pretty much copy pasted from w3:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-sm" id="confirm-rent-modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>         
</div>
```

Also there is also some custom style for container-fluid:

```
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 30px;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
```

When this code is place in `container-fluid` bootsrap div, nothing happens. When I put it outside of it (in `body` tag), the modal shows, but then disappears. But at least something happens.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me? Let me know if I'm missing something.

It could be an issue with your dependency versions?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rent-php').on('click', '.bike-rent-btn', function(){
        $('#confirm-rent-modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

```css
.container-fluid{
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md bike-rent-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-rent-modal">Rent</button>

    <div class="modal fade modal-sm" id="confirm-rent-modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <p></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh well, I guess it's something wrong with PHP/dynamically adding the button which triggers the event.

Comment: Oh my god I'm a complete retard. I was setting the `rent-php` div with: `$('#rent-php').html(result);` instead of `$('#rent-php').append(result);` which overrode the modal code... Thank you for your time.